# Drop Down List binding error from source base class

Tags: c#, oop, drop-down-menu, bind

I've a ddl and I'm binding values like this;

```
    List<ClassB> myobject =new List<ClassB>();
    myddl.DataSource = myobject;
    myddl.DataTextField = "X";
    myddl.DataValueField = "Y";
    myddl.DataBind();

public class ClassB: ClassA
{ 
}

public class ClassA
{  
    public string X; 
    public string Y; 
}
```

X and Y are not the properties of myobject but they are public properties of myobject's base class and I MUST USE myobject

I'm getting error says X and Y are not properties of list.

Has anyone any idea ?

Comment: what type is myobject? is it a collection type?

Comment: Dextererer show you code in the section where you posted the original question above.. please show what my object looks like.. come on now Dextererer

Comment: Dexterer paste the part of the base class where X and Y properties are defined and update the part of code which binds dropdowlist with real property names

Comment: It's very hard to find a solution when you don't paste the real code. Your list is now a list of **myobject** class while the classes below are **ClassB** which inherits from **ClassA** and the code of you base class names the class **A** only. I think that your problem is a typo and without the **real** code I won't be able to help you.

Comment: the code should look like this `public class ClassB : A
    {
    }

    public class A
    {
        public string X;
        public string Y;
    }`

Comment: good luck Dextererer I want to you to tell me if you get an error when you are trying to `Inherit` from `public class ClassB: ClassA` this question is wasting others time ..learn how to use Inheritance properly.. `I am voting to CLOSE`

Comment: either change this `public class A ` to `public class ClassA` or change the other  `public class ClassB: ClassA` to `public class ClassB: A`

Comment: You guys got it ? The error is not on compile time on run time. So
stop debugging it and if you 've an idea step forward otherwise stop being prig

Answer (score 0):

You should define `X` and `Y` as read-write properties. Below is a working code sample.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ClassB> myobject = new List<ClassB>();
        myobject.Add(new ClassB() { X = "1", Y = "2" });
        myobject.Add(new ClassB() { X = "3", Y = "4" });
        myddl.DataSource = myobject;
        myddl.DataTextField = "X";
        myddl.DataValueField = "Y";
        myddl.DataBind();
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
}

public class ClassA
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is strange, for me it works perfectly. Could you create a new project with a single webform `WebForm1`, add the `myddl` `DropDownList`control to it and put the code above in the code-behind file?